# in a rebol function which gets a variable as argument, how to retrieve the original variable

Tags: debugging, rebol

I'm debugging a script which doesn't behave like I wished;

I'm writing a small debug utility function, which would print the 'word followed by its value.
I wrote this:

```
debug: func [x] [print rejoin ['x " => " x] wait 0.5 ]
```

And, in my code, I'd like to call it simply like this:

```
phrase: "beer is good"
mots: parse phrase " "
debug phrase
    foreach mot mots [
    debug mot
    ;do something...
    ]
```

and I would dream that it would output on the console something like:

```
phrase => "beer is good"
mot => "beer"
mot => "is"
mot => "good"
```

but I can't find a way to retrieve the variable's original name, that is, its name out of the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your 'debug function and compare it to the source of '??, you'll see what you would have needed to do differently:

```
??: func [
    {Prints a variable name followed by its molded value. (for debugging)}
    'name
][
    print either word? :name [head insert tail form name reduce [": " mold name: get name]] [mold :name]
    :name
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not searched enough...

```
?? variable
```

does what I needed.

```
>> ? ??
USAGE:
    ?? 'name 

DESCRIPTION:
     Prints a variable name followed by its molded value. (for debugging)
     ?? is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
     name -- (Type: any)
```

Comment: On the topic of taking lit-word params, there is a subtle difference between passing parameters as lit-words and as get-words: ["Why doesn't Rebol 3 honor quoted function parameters that are parenthesized?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532596/why-doesnt-rebol-3-honor-quoted-function-parameters-that-are-parenthesized)