# Understanding the relationship between print and symbols held in blocks

Tags: rebol, red

**Scenario 1:**

```
red>> sizes: [small medium large]
== [small medium large]
red>> print sizes
*** Script error: small has no value
*** Where: print
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
red>> print first sizes
small
```

I expected scenarios 1 and 2 to have the same behaviour(either error out on evaluation or be treated as a symbol).

I am trying to understand if the following scenario is specific to `print` or a Red/Rebol concept that I should understand.

I understand that all words in a block are treated as symbols and a function is required to evaluate them(if necessary). So scenario 1 makes sense. But if we extract a word from a block(using `first`), it remains a symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

> I am trying to understand if the following scenario is specific to print or a Red/Rebol concept that I should understand.

The answer is "both". The core Red/Rebol concept to understand is that you can define the behavior of functions to dispatch with a kind of polymorphism based on the type it was passed.  And PRINT as currently written interprets a block! parameter as a sort of "print dialect"...which it evaluates before printing.  If you manage to slip it a WORD! value, it will print that word's spelling.

You managed to slip a WORD! as value without evaluating it by picking it out of a block, so it was the result of a function.  The evaluator only takes *one* step on each pass, so after running FIRST it doesn't consider it to be its job to look it up...the returned WORD! is data, not code:

```
red>> sizes: [small medium large]
red>> print first sizes
small
```

You could have done that via a literal word as well, which has the evaluator behavior in that single step of reducing into a WORD! and (again) going no further:

```
red>> print 'small
small
```

It could also be the result of the QUOTE function, which is "special" because it quotes its argument *(see `help quote` for the spec, and [this very interesting tidbit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14532885/211160) on the two different "kinds of parameter quoting"...a subtle but nifty distinction)*

```
red>> print quote small
small
```

But parameter quoting is the *exception* and not the norm.  So usually if you see something like SMALL unquoted and un-blocked in a sequence like that...you expect that the evaluator will see it, look it up, and choke if it can't find it:

```
red>> print small
*** Script error: small has no value
```

Because the decision PRINT makes when it is passed a BLOCK! is to evaluate that block and merge the evaluation results, when you write:

```
red>> sizes: [small medium large]
red>> print sizes
*** Script error: small has no value
```

...since PRINT does not quote its parameter, evaluation makes that effectively equivalent to if you had written:

```
red>> print [small medium large]
*** Script error: small has no value
```

PRINT sees the block and for that block's top-level assumes you want evaluation of that-which-can-be-evaluated further.  *(String literals, for instance are at the end of the evaluation road and evaluation of them is a no-op)*.  Spacing and newlines aside, it's a bit like you'd typed:

```
red>> print small
*** Script error: small has no value

red>> print medium
*** Script error: medium has no value

red>> print large
*** Script error: large has no value
```

*(Except it stops on the first error, of course.)*

Which brings us back to the question about if *"the following scenario is specific to print"*.  It is, in as much as that's how PRINT chooses to interpret a block parameter.  You might envision something PRINT-like that didn't evaluate unless something was in a PAREN! block, or had any other behavior you wanted...which is key to "dialecting".  (Current PRINT is somewhat simplistic compared to alternative proposals, and the simple thing it does is effectively REDUCE a block it is given.)

But accepting PRINT as-is the same steps that work outside of a block for tricking the evaluator could work here.  Here's three different ways:

```
red>> print ['small quote medium third [small medium large]]
small medium large
```

*(Quick plug: Many other variations on this theme are possible and in practice today in [Ren Garden](https://youtu.be/0exDvv5WEv4?t=243).  It's not a new evaluator, but it has a new PRINT...and that's the tip of the iceberg...)*

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct and the behaviour in the two scenarios is particular to `print`, or more particularly to `reduce` ([`reduce` is an alternate method of evaluation to `do`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/reduce.html)). `print` essentially is a three step process: `reduce`, `form`, then send the resultant string to `system/ports/output`.

```
>> message: "Hello"
== "Hello"
```

Reduces `message`:

```
>> reduce message
== "Hello"
```

Reduces the block:

```
>> reduce [message]
== ["Hello"]
```

Reduces `'message` (evaluates to the word `message`):

```
>> reduce 'message
== message
```

Reduces `first [message]` (evaluates to the word `message`):

```
>> reduce first [message]
== message
```

In your scenario, you can avoid evaluation by preempting the reduction of the block:

```
>> reduce form [small medium large]
== "small medium large"

>> print form [small medium large]
small medium large
```

Comment: thank you so much, I wish I could mark this answer as helpful too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a block of Strings that haven't been defined is better to use these "{}" brackets. The prin/print functions print it without evaluation.

E.g prin {small big large}